# How do i open a file via terminal with a specific editor?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, command-line, terminal

How do i set a default application to open a file with my preferred text editor? I am currently trying `open file.rb`. It opens text wrangler, but I want to open with another. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to finder, right click on your `file.rb` file and select `Get Info`.

In the Info Window you'll see a section that says **Open with**, expand that section. There you can change the default application to open that particular file. There's also a button labeled **Change All...** This button allows you to use the specified application for all similar filetypes (*.rb).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the name of the editor you want to open with, i.e. `gedit file.rb`, or `vim file.rb`. You can probably also change your default editor associated with that file type, depending on your OS, etc.